# Select records in one table where a field in this table is included in another table

Tags: sql-server

Basically I have two tables. Table1 has millions of rows. Table2 has very few rows.

Table1 has field1 which is a product ID (not unique). Table2 has field2 which is just a list of productID's that need to be included from Table1 in the select statement.

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected results, and show us your current attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
Join Table2 ON Table2.field2 = table1.field1
```

Comment: Excellent. Worked perfectly. Many thanks, much appreciated!